# Calling a main method with paint and thread using a jbutton from another class

Tags: java, swing

Guys I have two class here. When i call the main method of Class Game using a jbutton from my other class, only a frame with white screen will appear. here is the code. Thanks for the help. 1st class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel {

    Ball ball = new Ball(this);
    Racquet racquet = new Racquet(this);
    int score = 0;
    int speed = 1;


    private int getScore() {


        return score;
    }
    private int getSpeed(){

        return speed;
    }

    public Game() {


        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                racquet.keyReleased(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                racquet.keyPressed(e);
            }
        });
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    public void move() {
        ball.move();
        racquet.move();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {


        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);


        ball.paint(g2d);
        racquet.paint(g2d);

        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Showcard Gothic", Font.BOLD, 20));

        g2d.drawString(String.valueOf("Your Score:" + getScore()), 340, 30);


        g2d.drawString(String.valueOf("Game Speed:" + getSpeed()), 340, 220);
        g2d.drawLine(300, 400, 300, -50);



    }


    public void gameOver() {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "your score is: " + getScore(),
                "Game Over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        System.exit(ABORT);
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");

        Game game = new Game();

        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(550, 400);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (true) {
            game.move();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);

    }
}
}
```

Second class

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JPanel mainPanel;
    JLabel title;
    Color bgColor = new Color(51,137,237);
    JButton startBtn, regBtn, viewBtn, exitBtn;
    public Main(){

    setSize(550, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    mainPanel();
    setVisible(true);

    }
    void mainPanel(){

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setBackground(bgColor);
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);

        title = new JLabel("Ball Catcher");
        mainPanel.add(title);
        title.setBounds(130,1,500,200);
        title.setForeground(Color.white);
        title.setFont(new Font("Showcard Gothic", Font.BOLD, 35));

        startBtn = new JButton("START");
        mainPanel.add(startBtn);
        startBtn.setBounds(200,150,130,40);
        startBtn.addActionListener(this);
        startBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        startBtn.setFont(new Font("Showcard Gothic", Font.BOLD, 20));
        startBtn.setBackground(bgColor);

        regBtn = new JButton("REGISTER");
        mainPanel.add(regBtn);
        regBtn.setBounds(200,200,130,40);
        regBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        regBtn.addActionListener(this);
        regBtn.setFont(new Font("Showcard Gothic", Font.BOLD, 15));
        regBtn.setBackground(bgColor);

        viewBtn = new JButton("VIEW SCORE");
        mainPanel.add(viewBtn);
        viewBtn.setBounds(200,250,130,40);
        viewBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        viewBtn.setFont(new Font("Showcard Gothic", Font.BOLD, 15));
        viewBtn.setBackground(bgColor);

        exitBtn = new JButton("EXIT");
        mainPanel.add(  exitBtn);
        exitBtn.setBounds(200,300,130,40);
        exitBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        exitBtn.setFont(new Font("Showcard Gothic", Font.BOLD, 15));
        exitBtn.setBackground(bgColor);


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == startBtn){
            String[] args={};
           try {
            Game.main(args);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        }

        if(e.getSource() == regBtn){

            new Register();
            dispose();

        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());


                    break;  
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) 
        {

        }
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lot of issues with your code, too many to go through all, but it includes:

- Overriding a JPanel's paint method.
- Inside that paint method calling this super's paintComponent(??)
- Calling another class's main method from within a running class.
- Using `while (true)` in a Swing gui...
- ... etc

Regarding your main question -- don't call another class's main method as by doing this you're throwing out all of OOPs. Instead create an instance and call the instances non-static methods. Your code is freezing because of that `while (true)` by the way as it's blocking the Swing event thread. Instead of that, use a Swing Timer. But most important, throw this code out and start over.

Suggestions to improve:

- Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for Swing animations, not `while (true)`.
- Don't have a game loop running inside of the main method as it's too important a construct for that. Have it running in the main class that controls the game. The main method should be used mainly to set up the players and then start them interacting, and that's it.
- Don't call another classes static main method.
- Instead try to create clean OOP-compliant classes, ones that don't need this kludge to run.
- Write down your code specifications and plans before typing in code. Organize your thoughts first.
- Read up on Swing Graphics. Tutorial: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- Override a JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method, and be sure to call the ***same*** super method inside of it.
- Avoid use of null layouts as they will lead to brittle GUI's that look poor on most platforms and which are very difficult to debug, enhance or change.

Comment: Oh thanks for the help and suggestions. . I need more practice. :)